# ksqDB stream over Avro forrmated topic: SELECT column cannot be resolved

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have basic quick start setup in docker compose using ksqlDB 0.28.2.
I created topic and AVRO schema using external tool directly into kafka.
then I used:

```
CREATE STREAM patches
WITH (
KAFKA_TOPIC='onlinepatch', 
VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO',
VALUE_SCHEMA_ID=2,
KEY_FORMAT='AVRO',
KEY_SCHEMA_ID=1,
PARTITIONS=1);
```

to create stream over the topic.
After this my `SELECT * FROM patches;` worked fine:
[image]

But when trying to select on specific column: `SELECT patchId FROM patches;`

I'm getting error:
`SELECT column 'PATCHID' cannot be resolved.`

My goal is to create materialized table over that stream, to see only latest state of the data, but I guess I need to be able to access the columns right ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was some weird issue, when I repeated scenario again next day it work fine and I was able to create materialized view.